# Add internal page to admin menu

Tags: admin-menu

i want to put an internal wordpress page (for example Contact page) to the admin panel, in order to dont have to go though Pages->All Pages, 
is it possible?

with the above code it seems that it can only retrieve some pages, not all of them. 
In many pages i get bool(false) and the template page is for sure correct. in one page i get this

object(WP_Post)#823 (28) { ["ID"]=> int(13) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" 
["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-11-06 09:31:01" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-11-06 09:31:01" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(4) "Home" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(4) "home" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> string(0) "" ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2013-11-06 10:40:37" ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-11-06 10:40:37" ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) "" ["post_parent"]=> int(0) ["guid"]=> string(37) "http:// localhost/medetail/?page_id=13" ["menu_order"]=> int(0) ["post_type"]=> string(4) "page" ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) "" ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "0" ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["meta_id"]=> string(2) "11" ["post_id"]=> string(2) "13" ["meta_key"]=> string(17) "_wp_page_template" ["meta_value"]=> string(13) "page-home.php" }

also i noticed in this one that the http:// localhost/medetail/?page_id=13 is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

First of all you need a way to identify the page. there are different way to do it: by page slug, by page template...

I suggest you to create a fucntion that retrieve that page.

Let's assume the contact page has a page template called `'page-contacts.php'`.

```
function get_contact_page() {
  $args = array(
    'number' => 1,
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-contacts.php'
  );
  $pages = get_pages($args);
  return ! empty( $pages ) ? array_pop($pages) : FALSE;
}
```

If you want to use a different way to identify your page, change this function accordingly.

After that, create a function to add the menu item hooking `admin_menu`:

```
function my_contact_page_menu() {
    $page = get_contact_page();
    if ( ! $page ) return;
    global $menu;
    $menu[] = array (
      'Contact Page', // menu label
      'manage_options', // capability
      get_edit_post_link( $page->ID, '' ),
      NULL,
      'menu-top menu-icon-post',
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu','my_contact_page_menu');
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! My template is page-contact.php , i changed your code and put it at the end of the functions.php of my theme but its not showing anything in the admin menu..

Comment: @Thanos be sure the page is retrieved by correctly. Try to insert `var_dump($page);` just after `$page = get_contact_page();`.